# Arrowhead in Visio 2010 keeps changing from procedure to flat

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm creating a sequence diagram in Visio 2010. I currently have a flat arrowhead and changed it to a procedure arrowhead.  I then save it but every once in a while it changes back to a flat arrowhead.

Comment: Which shape has the flat arrowhead? What shape is it connected to?

Comment: @Paul Herber, it's connected to an activation in a sequence diagram.  I ended up deleting the arrow and creating a new one.